# ADB/fastboot over Serial/COM ports?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, usb, adb, boot-loop, fastboot

Long story short, my phone messed up and it's stuck in a bootloop. The phone in question is a Coolpad 7560U, also known as Orange Nivo, running Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean. Data and cache wiping do not fix the bootloop. USB jigs are not a valid method either. The usual means of connecting to it using adb or fastboot don't work anymore -- neither will detect the phone in any way. I have tried all of the power on button combinations. All I can manage is to get into the stock recovery mode (the same one the bootloop passes through) and a QPST "通讯中 Secboot" Download mode.

I am connecting the phone to my Windows 8 x86 PC through an USB cable. For a certain timespan during the boot loop, the following devices show up in Device Manager, all at once:

- 3 storage devices : One of them is a CD-ROM drive and the other two are generic removables - None of them are accessible, returning the prompt "Please insert a disk into drive *:".
- 4 other devices:

> **Under "Ports (COM & LPT)"**
>
> Coolpad Android AT USB VCOM (COM7)
>
> Coolpad Android Diagnostics USB VCOM (COM10)
>
> Coolpad Android NMEA USB VCOM (COM9)
>
> **Under "Modems"**
>
> Coolpad Mobile USB Modem Phone

These four seem like my only means of landing a connection to the phone.

**Update:** According to Alex P.'s answer, I can confirm that the "Secboot" mode puts the phone into a QPST Download mode. The 4 serial port devices do indeed allow for access to the phone through Qualcomm's QPST software suite, and probably impossible to push adb or fastboot commands through.

Comment: Is it a Samsung device? I have had success in the past using a jig to fix boot loops on Samsung devices

Comment: Have not heard of ADB or fastboot working over COM! Fastboot *uses* USB protocol **only**, adb both TCP/IP and USB.

Comment: Only thing is the COM ports are emulating USB. Are you using generic adb binary or the one supplied with the handset (by way of CD software installed prior and on first occasion of plugging in the device)?

Comment: Try this [linky](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=43674160&postcount=4) on XDA?

Comment: One last thing - try it on a older Win 7 or Win XP machine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serial interface you see is a Qualcomm DIAG interface. It has nothing to do with ADB/fastboot. It can be used to recover the phone though by flashing the proper bootloader. You will need to use Qualcomm tools like QPST and find the proper flashing image in QPST format.

Comment: which one are you referring to exactly?

Comment: the BL being locked is irrelevant. What you need to do is to flash the original BL anyway - so it will be properly signed. As for not being able to find the proper image - that's something to think about before you "mess up" a phone

Comment: messing up system partition won't prevent you from booting into the fastboot mode.